# What is the meaning of ring in spy ring?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrases

Why is a espionage network called a spy ring? What does ring means in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "ring" is a closed circle.

One's "circle" includes the people around you - those you know and with whom you interact.

A "ring," being closed, doesn't allow outsiders in - it's the term often used for a closed group acting illegally or in secret.

Unlike a "terrorist network" which is characterized by decentralized "nodes" or "cells," the members of a "ring" may be in contact, and share a common central point (home station, government agency, etc).

"Spy circle" just doesn't sound as cool, but "[spy ring (def. #10)](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ring?showCookiePolicy=true)" has a nice "[ring (def #14)](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/ring?showCookiePolicy=true)" to it :)

Answer (score 1):

A *spy ring* is a group of spies. Usually a closed group that could figuratively be considered a *ring*.